# Mockito - Spy bug - recording a when as an Invocation

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have some pretty simple code as shown below.

```
@Test
public void bugInInvokingASpyAndVerification() throws ColdDayException {
    //given
    Engine en = new Engine();
    Engine spyEngine = spy(en);

    Vehicle realDeal = new Vehicle(new Wheel(), spyEngine, new Brake());
    Vehicle spyVehicle = spy(realDeal);

    //When part - set-up stubs
    when(spyVehicle.start(true)).thenReturn("Sure");
    //Mockito.reset(spyVehicle);

    //then part - actual calls + verifications
    String x = spyVehicle.start(true);

    assertEquals(x, "Sure");
    verify(spyVehicle, times(1)).start(true);
    verify(spyEngine, atLeastOnce()).startEngine(true);
    verify(spyEngine, times(1)).startEngine(true);      
}
```

The above code seems to record the 'when' call as the first call to the 'start' & hence the first 'verify' fails. The code works only when I uncomment the call to 'reset'. I am using Mockito 2.1.0  on Windows, with Java 1.8.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed,  in the line `when(spyVehicle.start(true)).thenReturn("Sure");` you call `start`.
There are several ways to avoid this.

One of them is use `doReturn`:

```
 doReturn("Sure").when(spyVehicle).start(eq(true));
```

Notice, that here we are are doing stubbing and not calling the method.

Comment: Good answer.  Note that `eq` here is redundant.  You should just write `doReturn("Sure").when(spyVehicle).start(true);`